# How to add multiple child inside a Scaffold

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to add a button, below the listview to navigate to the next page! But I am unsure of the layout.

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context)
 {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title:const Text("Welcome"),
       centerTitle: true,
     ),
     body:Center(
       child:SizedBox(
           child:ListView.separated(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
             itemCount: entries.length,
             itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
               return Container(
                 height: 50,
                 color: Colors.amber[colorCodes[index]],
                 child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${entries[index]}')),
               );
             },
             separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
           )
               child: TextButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: child) // Where am i suppose to add this?
       )
     )
   );
```

I am unsure of the layout! Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check `Column` widget.

Comment: Do you want to navigate to next page than , you can use this, 
 Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()));  Here ,NewScreen is the page where you want to navigate. Let me know  if I am going right.

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap the `ListView` with a `Column`:

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context)
 {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title:const Text("Welcome"),
       centerTitle: true,
     ),
     body:Column(
children: [
     Center(
       child:SizedBox(
           child:ListView.separated(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
             itemCount: entries.length,
             itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
               return Container(
                 height: 50,
                 color: Colors.amber[colorCodes[index]],
                 child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${entries[index]}')),
               );
             },
             separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
           )
               child: TextButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: child) // Where am i suppose to add this?
       )
     ),
],
   );
```

After you done this, you can add as many widgets as you want.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This will not work unless you wrap the ListView with a Expandable widget and then adding the button at the bottom